# Getting 409 api/session on second request of join session openvidu-server

Tags: javascript, java, ubuntu-16.04

I had deployed openvidu-server on ubuntu 16.04 server using aws VM by following this [official link](https://openvidu.io/docs/deployment/deploying-ubuntu/)

I had tested it directly from openvidu-server.That's working correctly. 
But when i tried to run its [official hello world example](https://openvidu.io/docs/tutorials/openvidu-hello-world/)

i am getting 409 api/sessions when second user join a session.I hadn't encountered any error at my openvidu-server console logs.So if anyone have idea that what to do then please share about it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had resolved this issue by adding the ssl certification to my server. And also had added domain to run my server.But there was only issue with ssl Certificate. Please use wild card ssl which is highly recommended.